# Using INSERT ... SELECT with Date format

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using an INSERT ... SELECT query in my MySQL. Now, in my database is a column named "medDate" which I use for my medicine Inventories app. This has a type Varchar and is formatted in this way, "July 2014". Now I want to use the insert...select query to copy the previous month's records. But as I test my query to MySQL, there's an error which says incorrect datetime value. Can you help me with this? This is my query.

```
INSERT INTO medicinesinventory (itemName, compCode, classID, 
 medDate, price, beginningIn, newIn, 
 outMed, sales) SELECT DISTINCT(itemName), 
 compCode, classID, CURDATE(), 
 price, 0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0 
 FROM medicinesinventory 
 WHERE YEAR(medDate) = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%M %Y') 
 AND MONTH(medDate) = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE  - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,  '%M %Y');
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
compCode medID classID medDate   itemname  price beginningIn newIn outMed sales
GOLDEN     148   20    July 2014 sample    0.00   0          0.00   0.00    6.00
```

Comment: your date values need to match. you have string varchar and datetimes that is why its throwing the error. can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `year()` and `month()` require dates.  You can get the dates using `str_to_date()` because MySQL supports "partial" dates (i.e. those without days.  So, try this:

```
WHERE YEAR(str_to_date(meddate, '%M %Y')) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
      MONTH(str_to_date(meddate, '%M %Y')) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE  - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Alternatively, you seem to want to format the previous month in the same format and do the comparison.  That can also work:

```
WHERE medDate = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%M %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

As `medDate` is a string and not a DATETIME you can't use YEAR on this column, but you could convert the right side with DATE_FORMAT and to be consistent you should store the values in the same format.

```
INSERT INTO medicinesinventory (itemName, compCode, classID, 
 medDate, price, beginningIn, newIn, 
 outMed, sales) SELECT DISTINCT(itemName), 
 compCode, classID, 
 DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%M %Y'),  -- formatted this date
 price, 0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0 
 FROM medicinesinventory 
 -- and converted those in the where clause
 WHERE medDate = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%M %Y')
```

**Note**

It would be better, if you could change the data type of the medDate column to DATE.

Answer (score 0):

The **`YEAR()`** and **`MONTH()`** functions operate on expressions of datatype `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`.

If those functions are used on a VARCHAR expression, I believe MySQL will perform an implicit conversion of the VARCHAR to DATE (or DATETIME), expecting format to be `'YYYY-MM-DD'` (or `'YYYY-MM-DD %h:%i:%s'`)

I believe that's where the "incorrect datetime value" error is being thrown.

---

Just use an expression that generates the VARCHAR value you want to match `'July 2014'`, and compare the VARCHAR values:

```
WHERE medDate = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%M %Y')
```